# OutOfMemoryError on GridView scrolling in android

Tags: android, gridview, out-of-memory

> Hitting OutOfMemoryError while scrolling the gridview.

Adapter code:

```
    package com.example.gridviewexample;

import android.content.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


    private  Integer arrayElement[] = {
             R.drawable.rkt, R.drawable.images,R.drawable.sir,R.drawable.sir2,
             R.drawable.sir3,R.drawable.sir4, R.drawable.images1,
            R.drawable.images3, R.drawable.indeerx,
            R.drawable.index,R.drawable.rkt2,R.drawable.rkt3,R.drawable.rkt4,R.drawable.rkt5,R.drawable.sir2,
            R.drawable.sir3, 
    };


    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayElement.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int position) {
        return arrayElement[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(arrayElement[position]); 
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,200));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Any Suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: where is the logcat error report?

Comment: @Andro Selva,08-27 07:08:34.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 07:08:34.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-27 07:08:34.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-27 07:08:34.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
08-27 07:08:34.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
08-27 07:08:34.784: E/AndroidRuntime(1748).

Comment: you are hitting outofmemory error which is a little complicated to solve. Search for view holder approach and re do your Adapter class. That should be of some help

Comment: I have mentioned the best approach already. Search for view holder approach for baseadpaters

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid1, parent, false);
    }

    TextView item = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    item.setBackgroundResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return grid;
}
```

I use `TextView` to display the images, you can try to change `TextView` to `ImageView` for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Its a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8488), its not because of large files. Since Android Caches the Drawables, its going out of memory after using few images. But i found alternate way for it, by skipping the android default cache system.

**Soultion**:
Create a drawable folder in Assets and move the images to "drawable" folder in assets and use the following function to get BitmapDrawable

```
public static Drawable getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
    AssetManager assets = context.getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename + ".png")));
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer);
    return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

Refrence : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6116316/revisions

Answer (score 0):

this is a android bug out of memory ...b/c android heap memory cannot support large siz ...so first step u creat drawable folder put all images in drawable folder then all images extention .jpg b/c .png have alrg size and try to post this code in manifest file in application tag

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```